# Redirect to index page but not working an alert of javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to check if the user is not logged in then he cannot access to the patient-dashboard page and redirect to index.php thats working fine but when i add an alert of javascript in patient-dashboard page where i redirecting the user to index.php if not logged in then it will first show alert box then it will go to index page thats not working... kindly help..

patient-dashboard.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Login First');";
        echo "</script>";

        header('Location: index.php');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send headers before anything else.  The script is preventing the header from working.  Redirect to an informational page instead of using a script, and use meta refresh to take them back to the index.

The informational page is just an ordinary HTML page that says, "You have to log in."  You get them back to the index page like this:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.exmaple.com/index/.html">`
The "5" is five seconds.  You can probably just put `index.html` in the URL; I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">;alert("Login First");window.location = "index.php";</script>';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't need to have the different parts of the alert in different echos, and the header redirect is now before the alert.

**EDIT**This refresh way works as a redirect and gives the alert

```
<?php 

$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;

if($var1 < $var2) {
    header( "Refresh:1; url=index.php");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login First')</script>";

}else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Logged In')</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @shani i just edited it and using a random if statement (1<2) i got the alert and then redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// patient-dashboard.php
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['login_failed'] = 1;
    header('Location: ./index.php');
    exit; // eliminate errors and prevent the user from going any further
}


// index.php
if (isset($_SESSION['login_failed'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['login_failed'];
    die("Login First");
}
```

Or

```
// patient-dashboard.php
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login First'); location.href = './index.php';</script>");
}
```